# UILabel text not changing, however xx.title is working

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uilabel, uinavigationbar

I have two view controller. In first view controller I have list of names. When I click on that, I want the same name to be displayed in second view controller.

I have below code.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // PropDetailViewController is second view controller
    PropDetailViewController *prop = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"prop"];

    ListOfProperty *propList = [propListFinal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", propList.addressOfFlat];
    prop.detailLabel.text = myText;
    prop.title  = myText;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:prop animated:YES];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

and in `PropDetailViewController`, I have `@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailLabel;`.

What I was expecting is when I click say `Name 1`, I will see `Name 1` as text in UILabel and on the UINavigationBar too. However I only see `Name 1` on navigation bar and not on UILabel.

Comment: There was a similar issue just days before but I do not find it. However, if I don't find it then I'll try an answer.

Comment: If it doesn't work, why dont you try detailLabel.text = title in PropDetailViewController !

Comment: @Dpk : that is a great deal, but actually I don't wanted to show title. In title I will have static text as "Names"

Comment: UILabel is not yet loaded and before that you are setting the text.Thats why its not appearing. see my answer below.

Comment: @NeelamVerma he is already passing the text through a "Title", so whats the use of using another string as per your answer?

Comment: @Dpk: ok as per requirement , he can do [self.detailLabel setText:self.title]; it will also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not advisable to access an UIView item at that point in the program flow. When setting the value of prop.detailLabel.text the view may not have been loaded. When the view is loaded later then the UIView is updated with the default settings given in the XIB file in IB.

You should rather set an NSString property, lets say

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *propName;
```

assign it before pushing the view controller as you do. But use this property and not the UILable. And in PropDetailViewController in viewDidLoad do the following:

```
(void) viewDidLoad {
  // call super viewDidLoad and all the works ...

  self.detailLabel.text = propName;

}
```

Instead of viewDidLoad you could use viewWillAppear. Because viewDidLoad COULD be executed already when you assign the property's value.

If you want to be on the save side then invent a new init method where you hand over all the values that you want to be set upfront. 
But I never did that in combination with storyboard (where you may use instantiate... rather than init...) and therefore I cannot give any advise out of the top of my head.

Another clean approach would be to stick with the propName property but to implement a custom setter `-(void)setPropName:(NSString)propName;` where you set the property (probably _propName if you autosynthesize) AND set the UILable text plus setting the UILable text within viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
in .h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *detailText;
```

in `PropDetailViewController.m`

Change line of code with

```
 NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", propList.addressOfFlat];
    prop.detailText = myText;
    prop.title  = myText;
```

in ViewDidLoad:

```
[self.detailLabel setText:self.detailText];
```